# How do I split string into an array using blank lines as delimiter in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

How do I split string such as:

```
aaaaa
bbbb

aaaaa
ccccccc

aaa
rrrrt
```

into an array using blank lines as delimiter?

Comment: What exactly do you want the result to be?

Comment: Even though you have selected an answer you should edit your question to address @Tiw's question. The answer is not just for your benefit, so the question needs to be clear to all current and future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, with [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-split)

```
'aaaaa bbbb'.split
=> ["aaaaa", "bbbb"]
```

> `split(pattern=nil, [limit]) → an_array`
>
> Divides str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these substrings.
>
> [...]
>
> If `pattern` is `nil`, the value of `$`; is used. If `$`; is `nil` (which is the default), `str` is split on whitespace as if `' '` were specified.

UPDATE:

To split on empty line, you can use `/\n{2,}/` pattern. It also handles paragraphs separated with more than one empty line:

```
a = <<END
aaaaa
bbbb


aaaaa
ccccccc

aaa
rrrrt
END

a.split(/\n{2,}/)
=> ["aaaaa\nbbbb", "aaaaa\nccccccc", "aaa\nrrrrt\n"]
```

Comment: multiline, though? And they want to split by paragraphs, not by lines even.

Comment: ah, with corrected formatting, it's a different question

Comment: If you replace 'bbbb' with 'bbbb\n' (edge condition) in above your example, how code will deal with it?

Comment: You could also split by `/^\n+/` which preserves the trailing newlines on the non-empty lines.